# Jos Stam's stable fluids — why is the timestep multiplied by the number of grid cells?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, time-integration

One more question about [Jos Stam's GDC tutorial](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/nsp/course/15-464/Fall09/papers/StamFluidforGames.pdf) on stable fluids: in the advection step on page 8, the timestep for each dimension is implemented as `dt * N`, where `N` is the height or width of the grid. This corresponds to a position update:

$x_{prev} = x - \frac{\Delta t}{h} \cdot v_x$

where $h = 1/N$.

But why is $h$ involved in the backtracing of velocity? I thought the time evolution would just be given by $x = x_{prev} + \Delta t \cdot v_x$ without involving the grid size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stam's code is written in such a way that the coordinates of the cell centers correspond to integers. This way, the cell where a particle ends can be easily determined by rounding (e.g. i0 = (int)x;) Likewise the starting point of backtracking is simply given by (i,j) (see e.g. x = i - dt0 * u[IX(i,j)]). So the computational problem is scaled such it makes computation simpler / easier to understand.

Comment: Aha, of course. I forgot that the grid implicitly has unit length and height.